# Javascript for total price of cart- good practice and adding a function

Tags: javascript, cart

I am writing a simple cart that to handle user input before arriving at a sum that I pass off to my payment processor. I have code that works, but I'm not sure if it's the most efficient way of calculating the total. Secondly, I would like to add the possibility for a percentage discount when three of the categories are selected. I originally had a way that did a lot of checking through IF statements, but that was inefficient and there was also an unresolved issue with it. How would I go about applying a percentage discount to my preexisting code (if three of four of the item categories are >0)?

```
  var subtotal = 0;
  var veu4 = 0;
  var veo4 = 0;
  var vres = 0;
  var vcvl = 0;
  var vedb = 0;

  function update_price(pin) {
  quantity = parseFloat(pin.value);

  var callname = pin.name;

    if (callname == "item1"){
      price = quantity * 50;
      subtotal -= vcvl * 50;
      vcvl = quantity;
    }
    else if (callname == "item2"){
      price = quantity * 50;
      subtotal -= vres * 50;
      vres = quantity;
    }
    else if (callname == "item3"){
      price = quantity * 99;
      subtotal -= veu4 * 99;
      veu4 = quantity;
    }
    else if (callname == "item4"){
      price = quantity * 129;
      subtotal -= veo4 * 129;
      veo4 = quantity;
    }
    else{
      //commented out irrelevant
    }


 subtotal += price;
 passtotal = document.getElementById("ftotal"); 
 total = document.getElementById("ptotal");
 total.innerHTML = subtotal;
 passtotal.value = subtotal;
 passtotal.innerHTML = subtotal;   
}
```

}

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: don't compute the total in js, its open to client side tampering.

Comment: Ok thank you, this is the good practice stuff I am unfamiliar with. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do this, but this would be a bit more DRY.

```
var items = {
  item1: 50,
  item2: 50,
  item3: 99,
  item4: 129
};

var cart = {};

function update_price(pin) {
  quantity = parseFloat(pin.value);

  var callname = pin.name;

  // Get the total for this item with quantity
  price = quantity * items[callname];

  // Update quantity in cart
  cart[callname] = {quantity: quantity, subtotal: price};  

  passtotal = document.getElementById("ftotal"); 
  total = document.getElementById("ptotal");
  total.innerHTML = price;
  passtotal.value = price;
  passtotal.innerHTML = price;
}
```

I think your concept of totals/subtotals is weird.  It seems like your total/subtotal will always be equal to your last calculation of price * quantity.  Maybe your code generated is wrong.  As such mine will be slightly wrong too.  To fix it, make the total equal to all of the subtotals in the cart.

As for passing this data to your server, you should pass the items that will be purchased and the quantity. On the server-sider, the subtotals and totals should be recalculated.  I added your cart variable to help with this.  Just serialize this data and send it over to your server processing.  **Do not take the value of ftotal or ptotal to be accurate when you actually charge the user.**